# Count the number of times a string appears in a sequence

Tags: matlab, matrix, markov-chains

I have a matrix X which comprises of some sequences I have from a Markov Chain. I have 5 states 1,2,3,4,5. So for example row 1 is a sequence and row 2 an separate independent sequence.

```
    4   4   4   4   4   5   3   0   0   0
    1   4   2   2   2   2   3   4   0   0
x=  4   4   1   2   1   3   1   0   0   0
    2   4   4   2   4   3   3   5   0   0
    4   4   5   4   2   1   2   4   3   5
```

I'd like to count the number of transitions between states 1..5. ie. 1to1,1to2, 1to3, 1to4, 1to5. 2to1 etc.
Eg. 1to1 happens 0 times. However 4to4 happens 6 times. etc.
We can ignore the zeros, they are an artefact from importing an excel file.

Eg [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36099/estimating-markov-transition-probabilities-from-sequence-data#comment72678_36099) question but there, the sequence has been concatenated.  Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Actually, you have 7 4to4 transitions (4 in the 1st, 1 in the 3rd, 1 in the 4th and 1 in the 5th)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code that does what you want:

```
N = max(max(X));                                   %# Number of states
[P, Q] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);
Y = [X, zeros(size(X, 1), 1)]';                    %# Pad for concatenation
count_func = @(p, q)numel(strfind(Y(:)', [p, q])); %# Counts p->q transitions
P = reshape(arrayfun(count_func, P, Q), N, N)
```

Short explanation: all lines of `X` into one long vector `Y` (the padding is necessary so that there are no undesired transitions in adjacent lines). `p` and `q` hold all possible combinations for state transitions, and `count_func` counts the number of transitions in `Y` for a specific `p` and `q`. `arrayfun` invokes `count_func` for all possible combinations of `p` and `q` and produces matrix `P` accordingly.

For your example, this code yields matrix `P`:

```
P =
     0   2   1   1   0
     2   3   0   3   0
     1   1   1   2   1
     1   3   1   7   1
     0   0   2   2   0
```

where `P(m, n)` indicates the number of transitions from the *m*-th state to the *n*-th state.

---

**EDIT:** If you're interested in finding the 2-step transition matrix (that is, *i*-th state → *j*-th state → *i*-th state) as in your follow-up question, you just need to slightly alter `count_func`, like so:

```
count_func = @(p, q)numel(strfind(Y(:)', [p, q, p]));
```

This should yield:

```
P =

   0   1   0   0   0
   1   2   0   1   0
   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   3   0
   0   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: I see what this code does but it complains about needing only one row for some reason.  Did you use the above matrix as an input? Regards,

Comment: I ran this code again and it works. Can you tell me which line triggers the error exactly?

Comment: It's the `findstr` function.  Gives me the same with `strfind`. Error using findstr
Input strings must have one row.

Error in @(u)numel(findstr(Y(:),[p(u),q(u)]))

Comment: Then try changing `Y(:)` to `Y(:)'`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for introducing me to `strfind`!  I wonder why Y' was making a difference though. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. Although `strfind` can be applied to vectors, it is meant for strings, so it expects a row vector. In Octave it works on column vectors as well, didn't think it would be a problem. Anyway, I'm glad it works now.

Comment: @EitanT According to MATLAB R2012a Product Help on `findstr`: "Note: `findstr` will be removed in a future release. Use `strfind` instead." So it seems to me that using `strfind` is better way to do it for future compatibility. However, [in MATLAB online documention on findstr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findstr.html) the message is different: "Note: `findstr` is not recommended. Use `strfind` instead." So I wonder if they'll be removing `strfind` in a future release of MATLAB.

Comment: @nrz Yeah, it doesn't really make a difference to the solution. I changed it to `strfind` though so the solution won't use a deprecated function.

Comment: Any thoughts on how you could extend that gem to calculate the 2-step transition matrix?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the desired result?

Comment: @EitanT So for example a transition from state 1 to 1 with one other transition inbetween. This could be 111, 121, 131, 141, 151 etc  So it would still be a 5x5 but instead of comparing just 2 numbers side by-side we'd be looking at 3 together.  Like this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072206/constructing-a-multi-order-markov-chain-transition-matrix-in-matlab but for our matrix here. Do you think it would be easy?

Comment: Sure. This just requires a slight modification in `count_func`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks again, this is genius!  I'm loving that `strfind` command!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
%# Define the example data:
x = [
4 4 4 4 4 5 3 0 0 0
1 4 2 2 2 2 3 4 0 0
4 4 1 2 1 3 1 0 0 0
2 4 4 2 4 3 3 5 0 0
4 4 5 4 2 1 2 4 3 5
];

%# Number of different states.
N = max(max(x));

%# Original states.
OrigStateVector = repmat((1:N)', N, 1);

%# Destination states corresponding to OrigStateVector.
DestStateVector = reshape(repmat((1:N)', 1, N)', N^2, 1);

%# Pad rows of x with zeros and reshape it to a horizontal vector.
xVector = reshape([ x, zeros(size(x,1),1) ]', 1, numel(x)+size(x,1));

%# Compute the number of state transitions and store the result in ResultMatrix.
ResultMatrix = reshape(cellfun(@(z) numel(z), arrayfun(@(x,y) strfind(xVector, [x y]), OrigStateVector, DestStateVector, 'UniformOutput', false)), N, N)';

ResultMatrix =
 0     2     1     1     0
 2     3     0     3     0
 1     1     1     2     1
 1     3     1     7     1
 0     0     2     2     0
```